# Process query and bring result on the same page jsp

Tags: jsp, process

Process query and bring result on the same page jsp
i have created a signup page which includes label and textbox and register
on click of register button i have insert query(insert into sql db) which has to be executed and bring the result on signup page success or error
plz tell me the logic and a sample of code

Answer (score 0):

In servet

if details are not satisfied  dispatch page with error message  like below ..

```
try {
        HttpSession httpSession = req.getSession(true);
        httpSession.setAttribute("errormessage", message);
        req.getRequestDispatcher("register.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

make changes in  jsp like this

```
 <%
             String errormessage = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("errormessage");
             if(errormessage != null)
             {
             errormessage =errormessage;
             }
             else
             {
             errormessage ="";
             }

             %>
           <div id="login_error" class="common-box">
                <span><%= errormessage %> </span>
                <% request.getSession().removeAttribute("errormessage");  
                %> 
           </div>
```